# Mongoose elemMatch and inc query based on id

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

How am I going to write mongoose function that will query this `mongo` query based on a given **userId** (I could not add this to query, also need that).

```
db.users.update({ categories : { $elemMatch: { name: "Sport"  }  }  },
                {$inc: {"categories.$.points": 6666, points : 7777}})
```

That doesn't help me out.

```
User.findByIdAndUpdate(
        request.params.userId,
        //{ $inc: { points: 1 }},
        { categories : { $elemMatch: { name: "Spor" }}}, 
        {$inc: {"categories.$.points": 6666, points : 7777}},
        //{ safe: true, upsert: true, new : true },
        function(err, user) {
          if (!err) {
            return reply(user); // HTTP 201
          }
          if (11000 === err.code || 11001 === err.code) {
            return reply(Boom.forbidden("please provide another user id, it already exist!"));
          }
          return reply(Boom.forbidden(err)); // HTTP 403
        }
    );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [`findOneAndUpdate`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findOneAndUpdate) instead of `findByIdAndUpdate` if you want to match on anything beyond just the `_id`. You also don't need to use `$elemMatch` here as you're only matching against a single field in the `categories` array so a simple dot notation field match can be used instead.

So it should be:

```js
User.findOneAndUpdate(
    { _id: request.params.userId, "categories.name": "Sport" }, 
    { $inc: { "categories.$.points": 6666, points : 7777 }},
    { safe: true, upsert: true, new: true },
    function(err, user) { ... }
);
```